# MySQL - How do I add a "flag" column to a select query if date is expired (ie. less than today's date)?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One with peoples names (drivers) and one with their driving license (licenses) details and expires. I need to merge the two tables and list the driver's name, id number and whether the license is expired or not.

I have the following which returns all the drivers with their license and expiry but I would like to add a final column which states (expired/valid) based on the expiry date returned (timestamp).

```
SELECT d.name AS 'Driver Name', d.nric AS 'NRIC', l.expiry AS 'Expiry' FROM drivers d, licenses l WHERE d.driverID=licenses.driverID ORDER BY name ASC
```

I need a fourth column to be added which evaluates whether `l.expiry` is "less than" today, ie expired.

The output should be like this:

```
Driver Name NRIC Expiry Validity
Joe Blooggs 1234 1/1/14 Valid
Joe Blooggy 1235 1/3/14 Invalid
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by "licence record"? Does a given license appear many times in the `licenses` table?

Comment: A given license only appears once in the table, but each driver could have multiple licenses. They expire every year, and they are issued a new license each year, but the old one is maintained in the DB so I need to get the latest one then determine whether that one is expired or not.

Comment: Can a single license have multiple records in the licenses table then? What happens when a license is renewed?

Comment: No. A single license has one record in the license table. When a license is "renewed" the driver is actually issued with a new license with a new license ID. ie. 1 to many relationship (driver to license)

Comment: Then I fail to understand it. You said you needed "the most recent license record". Since a licence appears in the table just once, all records are most recent.
So the final question is this: can a driver have a couple of valid (not expired) licenses at a time? If not, then @Fabien TheSolution has it right. If yes, then nobody got it right.

Comment: A driver has only one 'active' license at a time. The system stores his historical license data. So he has a license for year 2013 - it expires 31st Dec 2013. Then he gets a new license and it expires 31t Dec 2014. This driver has 2 license records relating to him. I want to find the license with the "highest" expiry (this would be considered the active license) and then compare to today's date, and mark as valid/invalid.

Comment: This means @Fabien was the first with the correct solution. IMO, you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15a3f/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE drivers
    (`driverID` int, `name` varchar(11), `nric` int)
;

INSERT INTO drivers
    (`driverID`, `name`, `nric`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Joe Blooggs', 1234),
    (2, 'Joe Blooggy', 1235)
;

CREATE TABLE licenses
    (`licenseID` int, `driverID` int, `expiry` int)
;

INSERT INTO licenses
    (`licenseID`,`driverID`, `expiry`)
VALUES
    (1,1, 1406217600),
    (2,1, 1409217600),
    (3,1, 1432656000),
    (4,2, 1406217600)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT d.name AS 'Driver Name', d.nric AS 'NRIC', l.expiry AS 'Expiry',
CASE
    WHEN l.expiry < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) THEN "Invalid"
    ELSE "Valid"
END AS Validity
FROM drivers d 
INNER JOIN licenses l ON d.driverID=l.driverID and l.licenseID = 
                                       (select licenseID 
                                          from licenses l2 
                                          where l.driverID = l2.driverID 
                                          order by expiry desc limit 1)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15a3f/1/0)**:

```
| DRIVER NAME | NRIC |     EXPIRY | VALIDITY |
|-------------|------|------------|----------|
| Joe Blooggs | 1234 | 1432656000 |    Valid |
| Joe Blooggy | 1235 | 1406217600 |  Invalid |
```

Comment: This query will be problematic if a driver has multiple licenses - see the JOIN subquery

Comment: Euh...it's exactly what I did in my test...look at driver id 1, there is multiple lines in the licences table and it get the right result....not sure what you mean there ?

Comment: If a driver has only one "active" license at a time, then your query is right. 
You don't take into account a `licenceID` column in `licences` - you assume it stores driver and the date.

Comment: The `licenceID` column just appear in the OP notes...btw...it will not works if you have the same expiry date for 2 different licenceID but for the same driver...otherwise it works

Comment: It wouldn't work if a driver has more than 1 license - there's only one expiry date 'allowed' for a driver owing to the `JOIN`. Your query makes sense if a driver cannot have multiple non-expired licenses which I just asked OP about.

Comment: This is good Fabian, but it isn't working for my data. All are invalid:
`Driver Name Ascending  NRIC  Expiry  Validity
A Ayub Bin Abdullah  590725-11-5183  1406217600  Invalid
Ab Manan B Hj Masnun  740527-11-5503  1432656000  Invalid (should be valid!)

Abd Aziz Bin Daud  760313-08-6207  1426176000  Invalid (should be valid!)

Abd Malik Bin Ismail  660810-10-6311  1439136000  Invalid (should be valid!)

Abd Rahim bin Yaacob  680920-01-5769  1442678400  Invalid (should be valid!)
Abd Rashid bin Nubi  710201-06-5473  1422720000  Invalid (should be valid!)`

Comment: @nematoth ok...you expiry field is a timestamp...let me change my answer to reflect this

Comment: Had to make a couple of adjustments to get it to work but I got the solution based on your schema/sql. Thanks @FabienTheSolution

Added `ORDER BY sub_l.expiry DESC LIMIT 1` to the subquery so it read `(SELECT sub_l.expiry_date as 'expiry' FROM edsp_drivers_license sub_l 
WHERE sub_l.driverID = d.autoID ORDER BY sub_l.expiry_date DESC LIMIT 1)`

Comment: And then one more slight change to accomodate the timestamp instead of the date field:

`NOW()` changed to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: I also had to change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN so I got all the drivers and if they didn't have a license I would mark as "Invalid" based on an extra "IS NULL" check in the subquery.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for a `CASE` as the other answers suggest:

```sql
SELECT d.name, l.expiry < NOW() AS expired
FROM drivers AS d
```

Column `expired` will be of boolean type.

Use the host's code to display a string like "expired" and "not expired" based on something like (python) `("expired", "active")[row.expired]`. This will save valuable cpu cycles and network bandwidth on the db-server.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.name AS 'Driver Name', d.nric AS 'NRIC', 
SELECT (sub_l.expiry as 'expiry' FROM licenses sub_l 
WHERE sub_l.driverID = d.driverID
AND sub_l.licenseID = l.licenseID),
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT sub_l.expiry FROM licenses sub_l 
            WHERE sub_l.driverID = d.driverID
            AND sub_l.licenseID = l.licenseID
            AND sub_l.expiry > NOW()) 
     THEN 0
     ELSE 1
END AS is_expired
FROM drivers d JOIN licences l ON d.driverID = licenses.driverID
GROUP BY d.name, d.nric
ORDER BY d.name ASC
```

Comment: Excellent. That does answer my question but I realise now my data is more complex. Each driver has multiple license records from previous years so I also need to get the most recent license record then perform the same query. I believe I might need some sort of nested select statement to get the most recent license record? Should I edit the question?

Comment: I have edited the query. Can you verify? And yes, please edit the question so that the goal is clear for everyone.

Comment: Should the nested select not be something like this:

WHEN EXISTS(SELECT sub_l.expiry FROM licenses sub_l WHERE sub_l.driverID = d.driverID
       AND l.expiry > NOW() ORDER BY l.expiry DESC LIMIT 1)

Comment: There's no need for an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`, although we could use that. Nonetheless, I believe that `EXISTS` stops at first row that it finds and returns `true` (that would make a lot of sense)
Oh I see your edit. Fixing the query now.

Comment: The first row it finds could be the older license though, correct? So is it not best to make sure by "ORDER-ing" them DESC order by expiry and limiting to 1 result?

Comment: No, it won't be older - we have sub_l.expiry > NOW() in the `WHERE`, so it will either find some current licence or nothing - in which case it'll return false and `is_expired` will be 1.
However I'm not sure this query answers your question, since it seems you want to select all licenses for drivers instead of drivers and whether they possess any valid license or not.

Comment: Your join will trow the first line, so if you add "expiry" in the select, you will not get good results : See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4a1d/8

Comment: Yes, it turns out I misunderstood OP's needs and my solution is stuck halfway between one understanding of the problem and another i.e. it's a bad query. Your query is correct so I'll leave this as it is to let you get accepted answer which you do deserve.

Comment: @FabienTheSolution - Yes, it's selecting the earliest license document and not the latest one. For driver one, you have 3 licenses but it is selecting the license with the 'lowest' expiry (ie. earliest entry in the DB). It should select the license with the latest expiry for driver ID "1", ie. "2015-01-01"

Comment: This is the correct query I believe:-

`SELECT d.name AS 'Driver Name', d.nric AS 'NRIC', 
(SELECT sub_l.expiry as 'expiry' FROM licenses sub_l 
WHERE sub_l.driverID = d.driverID ORDER BY sub_l.expiry DESC LIMIT 1),
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT sub_l.expiry FROM licenses sub_l 
            WHERE sub_l.driverID = d.driverID
            AND sub_l.licenseID = l.licenseID
            AND sub_l.expiry > NOW()) 
     THEN 0
     ELSE 1
END AS is_expired
FROM drivers d JOIN licenses l ON d.driverID = l.driverID
GROUP BY d.name, d.nric
ORDER BY d.name ASC`

Comment: Actually not quite.. since I am using timestamp the correct query is:-

`SELECT d.name AS 'Driver Name', d.nric AS 'NRIC', (SELECT sub_l.expiry as 'expiry' FROM licenses sub_l WHERE sub_l.driverID = d.driverID ORDER BY sub_l.expiry DESC LIMIT 1), CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT sub_l.expiry FROM licenses sub_l WHERE sub_l.driverID = d.driverID AND sub_l.licenseID = l.licenseID AND sub_l.expiry > NOW()) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS is_expired FROM drivers d JOIN licenses l ON d.driverID = l.driverID GROUP BY d.name, d.nric ORDER BY d.name ASC`

Answer (score 1):

Yup, use the CASE expression.

```
select
  d.name
  , d.nrci
  , l.expiry
  , case when l.expiry < current_date then 'Invalid' else 'Valid' end as Validity
  ...
```